# HttpPost file upload status progress bar

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient

HttpPost showing the file upload status, I want to make progressbar. How can I do.
thanks

```
public void post(String url, File sendFile) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {  
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, true);
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity multiEntity = new MultipartEntity(); 
multiEntity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(sendFile));
post.setEntity(multiEntity);  
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post); 
if (response != null) {
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if apache httpclient has a ready-made solution for this but you could use an InputStreamBody (instead of FileBody) and wrap the FileInputStream in something that counts how much is already read. Compare this to the size of the file to see how far along you are.